# want to change text in div.main1 but inner text do not work

Tags: javascript, innertext

want to change the text in div.main1 but innerText does not work.
although in console it gives me random number I still can not change inner text in div.main1

```
enter code here
```

```
<HTML>
<div class="container">
      <h3 class="text">Good Luck!</h3>
      <div class="numbers">
        <div class="number-main">
          <div class="main main1">0</div>
          <div class="main main2">0</div>
          <div class="main main3">0</div>
          <div class="main main4">0</div>
          <div class="main main5">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="number-secondary">
          <div class="secondary">0</div>
          <div class="secondary">0</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</html>
```

```
enter code here
```

```
<script>
    const main1 = document.getElementsByClassName("main1");

   function randomNumber() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
    }

   main1.innerText = randomNumber();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a list.  You need to add an id to select a specific DOM, or use its index:

```
main1[0].innerText = randomNumber(); <- the first main1 it finds
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements, not a single element. Even if there is only one element returned, it is still returned as a collection.

You need to use it like an array and grab the first element it returns

```js
const main1 = document.getElementsByClassName("main1")[0];

function randomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
}

main1.innerText = randomNumber();
```